# Diagonal Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I would like to have some feedback on the following argument, which I used to prove a statement that I have stumbled upon recently and of which I couldn't find a satisfying discussion on the site.

---

From now on let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ denote a sequence of complex-valued functions defined on a metric space $(X, d_X)$.

> **Definition 1**: Let $\{k_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subseteq \Bbb N$ be a sequence of positive integers. We say that $k_n$ is a **law of extraction** if it is strictly increasing (meaning $\forall n \in \Bbb N, k_n < k_{n+1}$).

> **Lemma 1**: Let $\{h_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subseteq \Bbb N$ be such that $\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty}h_n = +\infty$, then we can always extract from it a subsequence $\{ h_{k_{n}}\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ such that it is a law of extraction.

*Proof*: Let $k_1 = 1$, then, having chosen $k_2, ..., k_n$ we shall define $k_{n+1}$ as $\min (\{m \in \Bbb N: h_m > h_{k_{n}}\})$ which always exists because $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered in the usual order and the set thus defined can not be empy by the hypotesis on the asymptotic behaviour of $h_n$.

> **Corollary 1**: From now on we can, WLOG, consider any sequence of positive integers diverging to $+ \infty$ as a law of extraction.

> **Definition 2**: We say that $f_n$ **converges locally uniformly** to $f$ on $X$ if and only if:
> $$(\forall x \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0 ), [(\exists \delta_{x, \epsilon}, \exists N_{x, \epsilon}):(\forall y \in B(x, \delta_{x, \epsilon}), \forall n \geq N_{x, \epsilon}, |f_n(y)-f(y)| < \epsilon)] \hspace{5mm} (*)$$

> **Lemma 2**: Locally uniform convergence is equivalent to locally uniform convergence on a compact metric space $K$.

*Proof*: It is clear that uniform convergence on $K$ implies locally uniform convergence on $K$, even if $K$ is not compact. Therefore, we just need to check the converse implication. Fix an arbitrary  $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\{ B(x, \delta_{x, \epsilon}) \}_{x \in X}$ be an open cover of $K$ and $\{N_{x, \epsilon} \}_{x \in X}$ be a sequence of positive integers, where each $\delta$ and each $N$ is given by $(*)$ applied to every $x \in X$. By compactness of $K$ there exists a finite open subcover $\{B(x_n, \delta_n)\}_{n=1,...,M}$, hence, if we define $N_{\epsilon} = \max(\{N_{n, \epsilon}: n = 1,...M\})$ it is clear that:
$$\forall n \geq N_{\epsilon}, \forall y \in X,  |f_n(y)-f(y)| < \epsilon$$
for every $y$ is in $B(x_n, \delta_n)$ for some $n = 1,...,M$. The proof is thus completed by the arbitrariety of $\epsilon > 0$.

> **Proposition 1**: If for every $p$ of $X$ the following holds:
> $$\forall \{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subseteq X, (x_n \to p \implies f_n(x_n) \to f(p)) \hspace{5mm} (* *)$$
> then $f$ is continuous on $X$.

*Proof*: Suppose $f$ is not continuous on $X$, then recall that on a metric space continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity so that:
$$(\exists p \in X, \exists \{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subseteq X):[(x_n \to p), (\exists \bar \epsilon: \forall N \in \Bbb N, \exists n_N \geq N: |f(x_{n_N}) - f(p)| \geq \bar \epsilon )]$$
Now, since $n_N$ clearly diverges to $+\infty$, by Corollary 1 we can, WLOG, assume that $n_N$ be a law of extraction, then we shall denote the subsequence $x_{n_N}$ by $y_N$. Moreover, notice that by $(* *)$ $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $X$ (think of the constant sequences), therefore:
$$\forall N, \exists k_N: |f_{k_N}(y_N) - f(y_N)| < \bar \epsilon / 2$$
and since $k_N$ can be clearly chosen strictly increasing (think of the definition of pointwise convergence) we can assume it to be a law of extraction and hence define a sequence by "filling in the blanks of $y_N$": $z_1 = y_1, z_2 = y_1, ...,z_{k_1} = y_1, z_{k_1 + 1} = y_2, ..., z_{k_2} = y_2, ...$. The key properties of this sequence are the following:
$$ \forall N \in \Bbb N, |f(z_{k_N}) - f(p)| =  |f(y_N) - f(p)| \geq \bar \epsilon $$
$$ \forall N \in \Bbb N, |f_{k_N}(z_{k_N}) - f(z_{k_N})| =  |f_{k_N}(y_N) - f(y_N)| < \bar \epsilon / 2$$
and since $x_n \to p$, the same goes for $y_N$ and $z_N$ because we have constructed them to be subsequences one of the other. In conclusion:
$$\forall N \in \Bbb N, |f(p) - f_{k_N}(z_{k_N})| \geq |f(p) - f(z_{k_N})| - | f(z_{k_N}) - f_{k_N}(z_{k_N})| \geq \bar \epsilon / 2$$
thus contradicting $f_{k_N}(z_{k_N}) \to f(p)$.

> **Proposition 2**: If for every $p$ of $X$ the following holds:
> $$\forall \{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \subseteq X, (x_n \to p \implies f_n(x_n) \to f(p)) \hspace{5mm} (* *)$$
> then $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ on X.

*Proof*: Suppose $f_n$ doesn't converge locally uniformly to $f$ on X, then the negation of $(*)$ yields:
$$(\exists \bar x \in X, \exists \bar \epsilon>0): [ (\forall \delta > 0, \forall N \in \Bbb N), (\exists x \in B(\bar x, \delta), \exists n_N \geq N:  |f_{n_N}(x)-f(x)| \geq \bar \epsilon) ]$$
in particular:
$$[ (\forall N \in \Bbb N), (\exists x_N \in B(\bar x, 1/N), \exists n_N \geq N:  |f_{n_N}(x_N)-f(x_N)| \geq \bar \epsilon) ]$$
so that we now have two useful sequences: $\{x_N\}_{N \in \Bbb N} \subseteq X$ and $\{n_N\}_{N \in \Bbb N} \subseteq \Bbb N$.
Now, since $n_N$ clearly diverges to $+\infty$, by Corollary 1 we can, WLOG, assume that $n_N$ be a law of extraction, then we can define a new sequence $\{y_N\}_{N \in \Bbb N} \subseteq X$ by "filling the blanks of $x_n$": $y_1 = x_1, y_2 = x_1, ...,y_{n_1} = x_1, y_{n_1 + 1} = x_2, ..., y_{n_2} = x_2, ...$.
and notice that Lemma 1 was necessary to guarantee that there are no overlaps between the assignments of the values of $y_N$.
The key property of the new sequence is the following:
$$\forall N \in \Bbb N, |f_{n_N}(y_{n_N})-f(y_{n_N})|  = |f_{n_N}(x_N)-f(x_N)| \geq \bar \epsilon$$
However, since $f_{n_N}(y_{n_N}) \to f(p)$ by hypothesis and $f(y_{n_N}) \to p$ by Proposition 1 and sequential continuity, the last relation is a contradiction.

> **Corollary 2**: The same statement as Proposition 2 holds also for uniform convergence if $X$ is compact, by Lemma 2

---

If anyone has time to review this I would be very grateful, in any case every input is welcome!

Comment: Proofs seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read any of the proofs.

Your definition of locally uniform convergence is wrong. It should be, "$f_n \to f$ locally uniformly on $X$ means that for every $x \in X$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $B_{\delta}(x)$."

Lemma 2 should say that locally uniform convergence is equivalent to uniform convergence. A more general statement is that on a locally compact metric space $X$, locally uniform convergence is equivalent to uniform convergence on every compact $K \subset X$.

Proposition 1 is missing hypotheses on the sequence $(f_n)$.

I'm not sure whether your proposition 2 is true, because your proof is using your wrong definition of locally uniform convergence.

Comment: I see your point! However this is the definition I was given. Also, if you think about it, my definition is weaker than yours, that is, your definition implies mine but not viceversa hence every result I proved is also valid for “classic locally uniform convergence”. As for Proposition 1, it is not missing hypothesis in my opinion, if there are missing hypothesis the proof should be wrong and if that is not the case then it doesn’t miss them.